# Json handling in angular $http post to express

Tags: json, angularjs, http, express, server

I am trying to post json data to express server using angular $http,

```
$scope.createTravel = function(){

       $http({
        url: '/api/travels',
        method:"POST",
        data: $scope.formData
        // headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
       })

};
```

the post is reaching the server in this console log statement

```
app.post("/api/travels", function(req, res){

    console.log(req);

});
```

without the json data.

Comment: Start investigating. First step: is it an anguar problem or an express problem? What happens when you print $scope.data to the console? What happens if you replace $scope.data by `{foo: 'bar'}`? When you open your browser dev tools and inspect the sent request in the network tab, does the request have the body you expect?

Comment: try to print  console.log(req.body.data);